# Knockout mapping select list to ViewModel

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm on my first knockout project and could use a little guidance. So far I can populate my main class in my view model from my service, but I'm trying to bind the select list box and the control isn't binding as I expect, although the data is available. While I now can get the select list data to populate the form, it isn't picking the proper index.

Your attention is greatly appreciated!

```
  // Initialized the namespace
    var Namespace = {};

    // View model declaration
    Namespace.initMemberVM = function (model) {
        var memberViewModel = {
            Id: ko.observable(model.Id),
            Married: ko.observable(model.Married),
            Name: ko.observable(model.Name),
            SalutationId : ko.observable(model.SalutationId),
            Salutation: ko.observable(Namespace.salutations[model.SalutationId]),
            Salutations: Namespace.salutations 
        };
        return memberViewModel;
    };

    Namespace.initSalutations = function (model) {
        console.log('called initSalutations');
        Namespace.salutations = ko.mapping.fromJS(model); 
    };


 // Bind the member
    Namespace.bindData = function (model) {
        // Create the view model
        var viewModel = Namespace.initMemberVM(model);

        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    };
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Namespace.getSalutations();
        Namespace.getMember(1);
    });
```

here is the data returned from the ajax call

```
[{"Id":1,"Name":"Mr","IsMarried":false,"TimeStamp":"2012-11-27T21:49:10.583"},{"Id":2,"Name":"Mrs.","IsMarried":true,"TimeStamp":"2012-11-27T21:49:10.583"},{"Id":3,"Name":"Ms","IsMarried":false,"TimeStamp":"2012-11-27T21:49:10.583"},{"Id":4,"Name":"Miss","IsMarried":false,"TimeStamp":"2012-11-27T21:49:10.583"}]
```

and here is the HTML

```
 <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr><td>User Id</td><td colspan="4"><label data-bind="text: Name"></label></td></tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Salutation</td><td><select   data-bind="options: Salutations, value: Id, optionsText: 'Name'"></select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td><td>First</td><td>Middle</td><td>Last</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td><td><input type="text" data-bind="value: FName"></td><td><input type="text"  data-bind="value: MName"></td><td><input type="text"  data-bind="value: LName"></td>
        </tr>


    </tbody>
```

update: after a little further digging I've observed that the reason why my select is not holding the correct index is b/c the Namespace.salutations array isn't populated in time when I'm trying to set that value to my memberViewModel.

Any guidance on how to manage that would be appreciated!

Comment: Update: I've modified my approach and can now get my data because I created a ViewModel on the server-side to bring back my main object and the supporting data for select lists. While this does cut down on the number of calls, I'd still like to see if anyone can explain how to perform multiple ajax calls.  Also, thanks Steve for the edits!

Comment: Can you post the complete source code, I can't see what the methods getSalutations and getMember are doing. A http://jsfiddle.net/ sample would be best.

Comment: Gladly! Here is a fiddle with the (mostly) working code. http://jsfiddle.net/poundingCode/ST6hj/1/  I say mostly b/c even though I can populate my dropdowns, as you can see by looking at them, they are not taking on any of the stylings from wijmo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are having similar issues, here is the remaining bits of code that you may find useful..
Again, if you missed it in the comments, I updated my first call to the service to bring back the data for my controllers as well as for my member. I'll adjust this approach later so that reference data is stored for later use separately, but for now...

```
 $.each(my.dataService.member.Salutations, function (i, p) {
                    salutations.push(new my.Dropdown(selectedItem)
                            .id(p.Id)
                            .name(p.Name)
                    );
                });


    // for creating Position Models
    my.Dropdown = function (selectedItem) {
        var self = this;
        self.id = ko.observable();
        self.name = ko.observable();
        // non-persitable properties
        self.isSelected = ko.computed(function () {
            return selectedItem() === self;
        });
    };
```